# Center content of a div vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

This is what Ihave so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/yisera/2aVpD/

There's a div I need to center vertically inside the `.jumbotron-special` container.

I tried using `display: table;` on he parent element and then use `display:table-cell` on the child element (the one with the H1 and H2) but so far no luck and I've ran out of ideas. I do not want to use absolute positioning since This needs to be responsive, and as the resolution goes smaller, the layout goes astray.

Any ideas how can I center it to the jumbotron parent div?

Comment: This might help you :) http://jsfiddle.net/mcSfe/

Comment: Why is this tagged with twitter-bootstrap?

Comment: take a look at the source code I provided. I'm trying to center a block element inside a `.jumbotron` from bootstrap. Everything else apart from that, is also from bootstrap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following code the contents of the `div` `.jumbotron-special`

add the following properties to the `class`

```
display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
```

Working Code:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/2aVpD/4/)

More on [Flex Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Read More on Flex [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: vote up for the use of display flex. This is a new property to me and haven't started playing with it just yet. Works like a charm.

Comment: @hsoto:READ this [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).This really helps to understand about flex

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#yourdiv {position:absolute; top:50%; height:800px; margin-top:-400px; }
```

Where `margin-top` is negative half of `height`.

Or, another effective method with 2 divs:

```
<div id="controller-div">
<div id="your-div">
Content here
</div>
</div>
```

Where, again with `margin-bottom` negative half of `height`:

```
 #controller-div    {float:left; height:50%; margin-bottom:-120px;}
 #your-div  {clear:both; height:240px; position:relative;}
```

Comment: This works. I tried, but since it is absolutely positioned, when the viewport goes small enough to trigger the responsive menu, open it and you will have the text on top of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

This here also works fine (you just missed to add `height:100%`)

```
.container-text{
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: #333 3px 3px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that has a bit more support than flexbox.

[Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/F6St7/).

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.full-jumbotron{
    font-size: 10em !important;
    margin-top: -70px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #333;
    min-height: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%;  
}
.container-text{
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: #333 3px 3px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}
.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you concern it does work like a charm, but I'll still stick with flexbox. I have no interest on giving support to crappy explorers. My audience are young entrepreneurs and so they know not to use them crappy explorers and just the case they decide to use any, I'll redirect them with my backend towards chrome or firefox.

Comment: Good on you!  Flex would be my first choice too.  Just remember to add the -ms- and -webkit- prefixes to get the best coverage with flex (it still requires vendor prefixes in a lot of mobile browsers, Safari and IE10).

Comment: Again, something I completely ignored. Will do. Thanks!